# Como usar código de javascript dentro do if Razor?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Na minha view, tenho seguinte de código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    @if(Model.File == true)
    {
       //Como usar javascript aqui ?
       //Exemplo:
       $("#target").click(function() {
        alert("Handler for .click() called.");
       });

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Não entendo muito essa do @ e sou muito leigo em javascript, mas por que no primeiro if você colocou o @ do lado de fora e depois você utilizou dentro da condição? Certeza que este não é o problema?

Comment: @Francisco, atualizei post, favor olhar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o pseudo-elemento `<text>` para realizar o que deseja. Seu código ficaria desta forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    @if(Model.File == true)
    {
       //Como usar javascript aqui ?
       //Exemplo:
      <text>
           $("#target").click(function() {
             alert("Handler for .click() called.");
           });
      </text>
    }

</script>
```

Outra forma seria utilizar o `if` fora do script, desta forma:

```
@if(Model.File == true)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Como usar javascript aqui ?
        //Exemplo:
        $("#target").click(function() {
            alert("Handler for .click() called.");
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Utilizar o if do javascript também é uma proposta válida, ou não?

Comment: Randrade qual é a forma mais correta ? O primeiro exemplo ou segundo ?

Comment: @MatheusMiranda Depende muito do que deseja. Razor em Javascript não é algo para combinar assim. No seu exemplo, em específico, **eu** acho melhor fazer o `if` fora do script, assim você evita carregar código desnecessário para a `View`. Agora, se possuir mais códigos, pode ser que o `<text>` seja melhor.

Comment: @Francisco Sim, e até mais utilizada, pois você usa apenas o que necessita.

Comment: Obrigado @Randrade, resolveu meu problema.